# Angular - global variable initialise once - example user name in page header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular application I store the logged in user name in a cookie.
And I want to display this user name in the web page header.

I can retrieve this in my controller as below and display in the page.

```
$rootScope.fullName = $cookies.get('user');
```

But instead of doing this in every controller, is it possible to do it in one place and always get this data ?

**Update #1:**

I don't use ui-view. I use angular route and a sample is as below.
Are there any simple approach please ?

```
var mdmApp = angular.module('mdmApp');

// Routes
mdmApp.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/listScopeAndFrequency/:reportTypeId', {
        templateUrl : '3_calendar/listScopeAndFrequencies.html',
        controller : "listScopeAndFrequenciesController"
    })
    .when('/listTemplateFrequencyExceptions/:reportTypeId/:consolidationScopeCode/:frequencyCode', {
        templateUrl : '3_calendar/listTemplateFrequencyExceptions.html',
        controller : "listTemplateFrequencyExceptionsController"
    })
    .when('/viewSubmissionDates', {
        templateUrl : '3_calendar/viewSubmissionDates.html',
        controller : "viewSubmissionDatesController"
    })
```

**Update #2**

I tried like below but could not get any dynamic values from REST API, I am only able to hard code the value. Not able to read from cookie, localStorage or var all are undefined or give errors.

```
mdmApp.factory('userService', function($http, $localStorage, $cookies) {

var fullName ;
    // Gets user details
    $http.get("/mdm/getUser")
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('userService > user : ' +data.fullName);
            fullName = data.fullName;
            $localStorage.user = data;
            $cookies.put('user', data.fullName);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
            console.log("Error while retrieving user details.");
        });

    console.log('fullName : ' +fullName);
    console.log('$cookies.get(user) : ' +$cookies.get('user'));
    console.log('$localStorage.user : ' +$localStorage.user);

    return { name: "hard code only works here"};
});


mdmApp.directive('userTitle', ['userService', function(user) {
    console.log('userTitle > user : ' +user);
  return {
    template: user.name,
  };
}]);
```

Comment: you could use .constant('key', 'value') or .value

Comment: are u using ui-view??

Comment: As @Vanojx1 suggests, it would depend on the `routing` you are using and "where and when" do you set `$rootScope.fullName` ?

Comment: @stackg91 Thanks I never used it... can u please direct me to some sample.

Comment: maybe this could help: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/04/javascript-angularjs-resolve-routes/

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a service? Those are specially designed for this task:

> Angular services are:
>
> - Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
> - Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.

---

How I do it (not necessarily the best way):

- setup an independent angular app (non-secured area) for user registration, on login store a token or some identifier in a cookie or the localStorage
- when instantiating the full angular app (secured area), create a service which will get back the previous value and inject it whenever you need the user

My `User` service looks like:

```
angular.module('app.core')
.service('User', User);

function User($rootScope, localStorageService) {
  let user = localStorageService.get('user');
  let token = localStorageService.get('userToken');

  if(!token) {
    //this loads another angular app which has nothing to do with this secured area (on /login)
    window.location = '/login' 
    return;
  }

  for(let i in user)
    this[i] = user[i]

  this.token = 'Bearer ' + token;

  //note you could reference this to the rootScope so that every scope can have the User object, this can be considered as bad practice!
  //$rootScope.user = this;

  return this;
}
```

Comment: Can you please see my Update #2

Comment: You can't expect an asynchronous function to return results inside a synchronous constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a service and a directory for this.

As soyuka explained. Services exists for the purpose of sharing data between parts of an application. I would then use a directive to handle the data in relation to the DOM, that is, to write to the header.

Service/factory:

```
app.factory('userService', function() {
  // do what you have to get your user and save the data.
  return { name: 'John'};
});
```

Directive. Notice the injection of the service. This could be done through a controller if you wish. It depends on whether you want your directives to have a dependency to the service.

```
app.directive('userTitle', ['userService', function(user) {
  // do what you want with the data
  return {
    template: user.name,
  };
}]);
```

Here the service just returns a dummy name and the directive outputs the name in the DOM.

Here is a [running plunker of the setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/An09I1YPVFj0THSQcpug?p=preview).

Comment: FYI you should not use anonymous functions to declare directives/factories etc.

Comment: It only works for hard coded return values. Not able to return from rest api.. please see my Update #2

Comment: @Jay See this small example of a factory returning data from a REST resource: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11#service There is a lot of information around for this, so take a look around.

Comment: @soyuka Can you elaborate on that? I don't know why this is preferred.

Comment: When debugging it's a lot cleaner/easier when using named functions. Also, it's what most style guide advocate :).